# How to find index of the line?

Tags: android

i am using following code to read data from file but i am unable to find index of the line?

```
public static ArrayList<String> searchInFile(String word) {


    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    FileReader fileReader = null;
    try {
        fileReader = new FileReader(new File("input.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        System.err.println("File input.txt not found!");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file);
    String line;
    try {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
           if (line.contains(word)) {
              result.Add(line);
           }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error when processing the file!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Unexpected error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
    return result;
}
```

so how can i find index of the line??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to create a counter integer variable that can keep track of the line index for you.

```
   int ctr =0;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       if (line.contains(word)) {
          result.Add(line);
       }
       ctr++;
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: yes its helps me but i want to found index of the line for another puropose can i found the index of the line???

Comment: I believed you can't do i with BufferedReader. When you're reading a file, to start there's no way to know how many lines of line there is (unless you count it yourself using a counter), that's why while loop is being used, it will loop until the end of file.  I'm not sure but there might be a framework out there that might get you achieved what you need, not using BufferedReader.